# Generate table row dynamically on AJAX success

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table

What I'd like to do is this : when the user clicks on send, I want the data to be displayed in a `<tr/>` (with each field nested in its own `<td/>`).

I already wrote a script that actually does this, but the system is not dynamic yet.

HTML :

```
<form name="contact" method="post" action="">
    <p>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="mail">Mail</label>
        <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
    </p>
</form>
<table id="results"></table>
```

JS :

```
$(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {

        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var age = $("input#age").val();
        var mail = $("input#mail").val();

        var dataString = [name, age, mail];
        var n = dataString.length;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
                $('#results').append(
                    $('<tr>')
                        .append($('<td>').append(dataString[0]))
                        .append($('<td>').append(dataString[1]))
                        .append($('<td>').append(dataString[2]))
                );
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
})
```

As you can see, I grab the fields manually with `dataString[x]`, but how can I make this system **dynamic**?

I was thinking of using a loop like the following but I can't seem to make it work :

```
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    row += "$('<td>').append("+dataString[i]+")";
}

$('#results').append(
    $('<tr>')
        .append(row)
);
```

Any hint on how to do this? Or would you have a cleaner solution?

Comment: When you actually click on submit button,the form gets submitted and page gets refreshed. You could change the input type to button and use your existing JS code.

Comment: @vimalnath No it doesn't; the `return false;` at the end of the function bound to the event handler prevents that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line of code:

```
row += "$('<td>').append("+dataString[i]+")";
```

isn't creating an element and appending data to it, it's just concatenating the `row` variable and a string literal (that contains jQuery code).

Why not make `row` an **actual** row - rather than a string that contains the contents of a row - then append that in the `success` callback handler instead:

```
var row = $('<tr>');
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    row.append($('<td>').html(dataString[i]));
}
```

Then:

```
$('#results').append(row);
```

Comment: I was aware of the problem but couldn't figure out how to solve it. Excellent, thank you very much for that.

Comment: I'm thinking, what if I want to have multiple forms (with different number of fields) on the same page? Is there a better way to implement this script than simply reproducing it with different `ids`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var row = '<tr>';
var col = '';
for(var i=0;i<dataString.length;i++)
    col += '<td>'+dataString[i]+'</td>';
row += '</tr>';
$('#results').append(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it will definitely work.

```
var str ='<tr>';
$.each(dataString, function(i){
    str += '<td>' + this + '<td>';
}
$('#results').append(str + '</tr>');
```